# TypeError: Ui_MainWindow.on_click() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pressed'

Tags: python, user-interface

so im trying to make a program that will tell the user his mouse position when he clicks anywhere on the screen but im getting the error: TypeError: Ui_MainWindow.on_click() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pressed'
i dont understand why this is happening and ive tried switching the position of the "self" variable in the on_click function but it didnt fix it and i need the self parameter

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PIL import ImageGrab
from pynput import mouse
import pyautogui
import time

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(306, 145)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label_x = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_x.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 90, 71, 41))
        self.label_x.setScaledContents(False)
        self.label_x.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_x.setWordWrap(False)
        self.label_x.setObjectName("label_x")
        self.label_y = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_y.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 90, 71, 41))
        self.label_y.setScaledContents(False)
        self.label_y.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_y.setWordWrap(False)
        self.label_y.setObjectName("label_y")
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 20, 111, 61))
        self.button.setObjectName("button")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.onPosButtonClick)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Bot"))
        self.label_x.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.label_y.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Pick Location"))
        

    def on_click(self, x, y, button, pressed):
        if pressed:
            print('{0} at {1}'.format(
            'Pressed' if pressed else 'Released',
            (x, y)))
            #self.label_x.setText(QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", str(x)))
            #self.label_y.setText(QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", str(y)))
            mouse.Listener.stop()

    listener = mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click)

    def onPosButtonClick(self):
        self.listener.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

new to python btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your listener (`on_click`) is a class member, you must provide an object when you set the callback.  That means `listener` cannot be a class variable, as you have it now.  Instead, you should do this in your `setupUi` function:

```
        self.listener = mouse.Listener(on_click=self.on_click)
```

However, you shouldn't needs to use `pynput` for this at all.  Qt can do this kind of mouse capture.